# Default filters in SourceTree history

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

In the Atlassian SourceThree software I would like to have as a default filter configuration for my history 
  [Current branch] + [First parent only]

The default one is different and it is quite annoying for me to always switch. 
[image: Default filters]

Thank you

Comment: I am after this functionality as well, did you find anything?

Comment: no, it's been weeks, posted almost everywhere, no clue yet

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added to sourcetree in version 1.2.X so now its a build in option.

Click on the **File Status** segmented control in the top left corner.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Above the **Files staged in the index** area set the filters to **Tree View** and **Show All**. All of your files will appear in the **Files in the working tree** area.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Select one or more files and/or folders, right click and select **Log Selected...**.

[image: Screenshot 3]